# Do using trackballs put more stress on the hand, wrist and arm than a traditional mouse?

Tags: computers, repetitive-strain-injury, ergonomics

I have read and heard contradicting personal experiences on how good trackballs are to avoid RSI as they put more stress on the hand, wrist and arm than a traditional mouse.

Do using trackballs put more stress on the hand, wrist and arm than a traditional mouse?

I am interested in both thumb trackballs and finger trackballs.

[image]

Comment: I am still interested in this question.

Comment: So any answer is welcome!

Comment: I think you would have to define more precisely how you use it. Some people use the ambidextrous mouse by resting the lower half of their palm on the back of the mouse, some people hover (which would undoubtedly cause strain). You'd also have to measure the muscle pressure the user is using to roll the trackball or press buttons, which would be a determining factor. Also, are we taking into account the effects of EMR?

Comment: @MicroMachine Let's focus on the most ergonomic way of using such mice. EMR=?

Answer (score -5):

I am currently using a logitech ambidextrous trackball and I am starting to develop pain for clicking with the thumb. The wrist seems to remain stable, but there is still a certain amount of tension when moving the ball in the wrist.

Else at my job, I try to move the mouse by moving my whole arm instead of the wrist to reduce wrist pain. There does not seem to be a perfect solution.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.